# splitting int from a string

Tags: c++

I have string with number on ints seperated by space delimiter. Can some one help me how to split the string into ints. I tried to use find and then substr. Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: I am unsure what exact format you are describing - just space-seperated numbers? An example string would help.

Comment: Google Search "splitting string c++" gives: http://oopweb.com/CPP/Documents/CPPHOWTO/Volume/C++Programming-HOWTO-7.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a stringsteam:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string s = "100 123 42";
    std::istringstream is( s );
    int n;
    while( is >> n ) {
         // do something with n
    }
}
```

Comment: if there is only two values like 100 123 every time is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: @brett What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: If there's always two numbers, you can do: `int x, y; is >> x >> y;` to extract them both without a loop.

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed as part of [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/c-how-to-split-a-string)

Also, you can use boost library split function to achieve the splitting without a loop in your program.
Eg.

boost::split(epoch_vector, epoch_string, boost::is_any_of(","));

Answer (score 1):

A version using boost. The stringstream version from Neil is so much simpler!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

int main()
{
  const std::string str( "20 30 40 50" );
  std::vector<int> numbers;
  boost::tokenizer<> tok(str);
  std::transform( tok.begin(), tok.end(), std::back_inserter(numbers), 
                  &boost::lexical_cast<int,std::string> );
  // print them
  std::copy( numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,"\n") ); 
}
```

Comment: You don't even need boost for this. You can simply construct an instance of `std::istringstream is(str);` and then do `std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(is), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(numbers));`

Comment: @reko_t Nice! Does the istream_iterator expect space delimited items, or can it also handle other delimiters?

Comment: It expects space delimited items, it can't handle other delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble when reading and converting more than one string (I found I had to clear the string stream). Here a test I made with multiple int/string conversions with read/write to an i/o file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // for the file i/o
#include <string>  // for the string class work
#include <sstream> // for the string stream class work

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Aux variables:
    int aData[3];
    string sData;
    stringstream ss;

    // Creation of the i/o file:
    // ...
    // Check for file open correctly:
    // ...

    // Write initial data on file:
    for (unsigned i=0; i<6; ++i)
    {
        aData[0] = 1*i;
        aData[1] = 2*i;
        aData[2] = 3*i;

        ss.str(""); // Empty the string stream
        ss.clear();
        ss << aData[0] << ' ' << aData[1] << ' ' << aData[2];
        sData = ss.str(); // number-to-string conversion done

        my_file << sData << endl;
    }

    // Simultaneous read and write:
    for (unsigned i=0; i<6; ++i)
    {
        // Read string line from the file:
        my_file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        getline (my_file, sData); // reads from start of file

        // Convert data:
        ss.str(""); // Empty the string stream
        ss.clear();
        ss << sData;
        for (unsigned j = 0; j<3; ++j)
            if (ss >> aData[j]) // string-to-num conversion done
                ;

        // Write data to file:
        my_file.seekp(0, ios::end);
        my_file << 100+aData[0] << ' '; // appends at the end of stream.
        my_file << 100+aData[1] << ' ';
        my_file << 100+aData[2] << endl;
    } 
    // R/W complete.

    // End work on file:
    my_file.close();

    cout << "Bye, world! \n";

    return 0;
}
```