# C++ split string into array

Tags: c++, string

Several answers (like [splitting int from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421817/splitting-int-from-a-string)) are proposing

```
#include <sstream>
```

Unforunately, doesn't compile for me (error "sstream: No such file or directory").
I found I can use

```
#include <strstream>
```

instead. Ok, now, with

```
std::string s = "100 123 42";
std::istringstream is( s );
```

I got "undeclared variable `istringstream' (first use here)".
Ok, trying out:

```
std::istrstream is(s);
```

Almost ok. Error: "no matching function for call to `istrstream::istrstream (string &)'".
But at least it compiles with:

```
std::istrstream is();
```

So I feel I'm somewhere near:) What's missing?

Comment: `#include <sstream>`, `<strstream>` is deprecated or perhaps obsolete. Anyway `<sstream>` is what you want.

Comment: You have to use `#include <strstream>` instead of `#include <strstream>`?

Comment: [What doesn't compile ?](http://ideone.com/ERBFqX)

Comment: If you don't have an `sstream` header (I imagine this is what you were trying to say), switch to a compiler made in the last 15 years. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @intery: g++; compiling out of sublime text 3

Answer (score 0):

ok, I installed Code Blocks, and used mingr32-g++ compiler.
My current builder configuration:

```
{
"cmd": ["mingw32-g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",
"path":"C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin",
    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["g++", "$file", "-o", "$file_base_name", "&&", "$file_path/$file_base_name"],
            "shell": true
        }
    ]
}
```