# give the line input to vector until EOL

Tags: c++, vector

```
2
5
3 4 5 2 1
5
4 4 4 2 1
```

is the input, where `2` is the number of test cases, `5` is "not" the size of the vector, I have to read the whole line into the vector, but only able to read one line with the code I wrote. Can you suggest better code to read the input?

```
int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n;
        char c;
        cin>>n;
        getchar();
        vector<int> V;
       while((c = getchar()) != '\n'){ 
            if(atoi(&c)!=0) V.push_back(atoi(&c));
       }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your code work ? Do you have any issue with that code ? If yes, please describe ? Or does that code work well, and you just want to know how to improve it ? If yes, in which way do you want to improve it (for example: faster code ? higher performance ? shorter code) ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 the code only reads first test case but not the second one

Comment: Does the first test case include the first 5 lines in your question ? Can you show us the second test case ? Or is it your second test case "5 - 
4 4 4 2 1" ?

Comment: I think you can only read integers between 1 to 9. Use `getline` and `sstream` as shown : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421817/splitting-int-from-a-string/29326185

Comment: @Job_September_2020 First test case:"5 -3 4 5 2 1", second test case:"5 - 4 4 4 2 1"

Comment: @anfjnlnl, In your function, can you change the variable "char c" to "int a", and then you can use "cin >> a" to read the integer and store it directly into "vector V" ? That way, you don't need to call "getChar()" twice, and don't need to call "atoi()" twice.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 then how can I put a condition for EOF in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--){
        int n, j;
        cin >> n;
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        string s;
        getline(cin, s);
        istringstream iss(s);
        vector<int> V;
        while (iss >> j){ 
            V.push_back(j);
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```